# Why does parallel slow down after a while?

Tags: linux, wget, gnu-parallel

I'm executing 60 scripts with GNU parallel(they all have `wget` commands in there)but I have noticed that after a few hours execution will slow down a bit. What could be causing this?

I'm executing parallel with this command: `parallel -j 60 < list` where "list" is just a file with directories to 60 scripts.

I'm on a CentOS 6.5 machine.

Comment: Since you use `wget` it might be highly related to network issues for the slower execution of the scripts.

Comment: If I where to stop the execution at any given time and restart it, it would start going fast again, what could I do to see if this is related to a network problem?

Comment: Recently I was extracting billions of rows of data from the internet. From my understanding, when you start the execution not all the 60 processes clog the network traffic initially. However, as the time frame increases, the network traffic increases and the bandwidth is fully utilized. Also, it might be related to the CPU usage.

Comment: Though theory wise it is possible to run multiple threads, it is highly machine dependent. If your machine is single core and you run 60 processes, not all 60 processes will take place in parallel. I am not sure of this concept but this is definitely another reason for the slowness.

Comment: @Ramesh in ```htop``` I see minimal CPU usage and network usage remains constant. This VM(hosted on kvm)has 8 threads and 24GBs of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *Understanding the Linux Kernel*:

> In Linux, process priority is dynamic. The scheduler keeps track of what processes are doing and adjusts their priorities periodically; in this way, processes that have been denied the use of the CPU for a long time interval are boosted by dynamically increasing their priority. Correspondingly, processes running for a long time are penalized by decreasing their priority.

Comment: Is there a way I can force a high priority?

Comment: Use the renice command.

Comment: Will the ```renice``` command affect the commands invoked by the bash scripts and parallel?

Comment: If you renice the parent process, all *future* spawned children will share that niceness value.